# Выборка по нескольким диапазонами

Tags: php, mysql

Задача сделать выборку из базы с несколькими диапазонами.

Делаю сейчас так:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM items 
        WHERE add = 'on' AND text1 BETWEEN '100', 
        AND '1000' AND text2 BETWEEN '300', 
        AND '3000' AND text3 BETWEEN '200', 
        AND '2000' 
        ORDER BY field_int_1";
```

Но что-то не фурычит. Подскажите как сделать выборку с несколькими диапазонами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если необходимо именно так, то объединяй в скобки

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE (price BETWEEN '1' AND '5') AND (count BETWEEN '1' AND '3')
```

Твой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM items 
    WHERE add = 'on' 
    AND (text1 BETWEEN '100' AND '1000')
    AND (text2 BETWEEN '300' AND '3000')
    AND (text3 BETWEEN '200' AND '2000')
ORDER BY field_int_1
```

Comment: @alexsis20102 а откуда берутся диапазоны? Может их лучше хранить в таблице (или, хотя бы, во временной таблице?